# Power BI Find duplicates and then find if they are exact duplicates within other coulmns

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying first to find the duplicates of a CODE (random serial number). I was able to count the duplicates and see that a couple have a values >1

```
Rule1 = 

Var CountDups = [CODE#]
RETURN

CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS('Table'),
    all('Table'),
    'Table'[CODE#] = CountDups 
)
```

That allowed us to find duplicates and how many times they are duplicated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvA3S.png)

I want to compare if two other columns (E and F) within the table match.

```
Rule 2 = 
IF(
 'Table'[Rule1]>1, 
Check if INFO1=INFO1 (comparing them to each other)

.....

Rule3 = 
IF(
 'Table'[Rule1]>1, 
Check if INFO2=INFO2 (comparing them to each other)
```

I have attached an example. So, once we have a duplicate CODE#, I want to make sure that column B (INFO1) and column C (INFO2) are consistent.

I have attached the logic I am pursuing in parentheses inside columns E and F.

The other rows for column E and F can be populated, but I only want to focus on duplicates. Once a duplicate is found, show/test that they are exact duplicates across the other columns.

Comment: Is there any scope of having a CODE in 3 row? if yes, then how INFO1=INFO1 and INFO2=INFO2 will be compared?

Comment: @mkRabbani Yes, so every-time there is a row that have the same CODE# it will then compare info1 and info2 from CODE# A to CODE#B (assuming A and B are equal). Your example (screenshot) got it right. I wasn't able to do it myself (even with your script). I will make reply to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need these below 3 measures-

```
Rule1 = 

VAR current_row_code = compare_row_column[code]

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS(compare_row_column),
    FILTER(
        ALL(compare_row_column),
        compare_row_column[code] = current_row_code
    )
)
```

```
rule 2 = 

VAR current_row_code = compare_row_column[code]

VAR info_1_count =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(compare_row_column[info1]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(compare_row_column),
        compare_row_column[code] = current_row_code
    )
)

VAR info_1_distinct_count =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(compare_row_column[info1]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(compare_row_column),
        compare_row_column[code] = current_row_code
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    info_1_count = 1, 
    BLANK(),
    IF(
        info_1_count = info_1_distinct_count, 
        "No", 
        "Yes"
    )
)
```

```
rule 3 = 

VAR current_row_code = compare_row_column[code]

VAR info_2_count =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT(compare_row_column[info2]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(compare_row_column),
        compare_row_column[code] = current_row_code
    )
)

VAR info_2_distinct_count =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(compare_row_column[info2]),
    FILTER(
        ALL(compare_row_column),
        compare_row_column[code] = current_row_code
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    info_2_count = 1, 
    BLANK(),
    IF(
        info_2_count = info_2_distinct_count, 
        "No", 
        "Yes"
    )
)
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: For the first rule I got all the values as 1 even though the CODE# does repeat (mine worked the Rule1 I have above) so not sure why yours didn't. Now for rule 2 and 3the screenshot does exactly what I want to, but I am not sure why all of mine show as blank. I will make another comment with the code.

Comment: Rule2 = 

VAR info_1_count =
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Table'[info1]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
      'Table'[CODE#] = MIN('Table'[CODE#])
    )
)

VAR info_1_distinct_count =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[info1]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Table'),
      'Table'[CODE#] = MIN('Table'[CODE#])
    )
)

RETURN 
IF(
    info_1_count = 1, 
    BLANK(),
    IF(
        info_1_count = info_1_distinct_count, 
        "No", 
        "Yes"
    )
)

Comment: All 3 rules are here considering Measure. Are you working with custom columns?

Comment: Yes, @mkRabbani so the code I pasted above is only for Rule 2 and that one is focusing on column: info1 (which is alphanumerical). So in your screenshot it would be trying to compare CA to EU and give No as an answer since they don't match.

Comment: Code for custom column will be slightly different. I am updating all 3 code soon.

Comment: Thank you @mkRabbani  ! I will give it a try

Comment: Thanks @mkRabbani that did the job!

Comment: Hi @Pepe, nice to see that it helped :)